# What is the preferred structure of a Magento 2 project under VCS?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, setup, git

When I start a new M2 project, the first thing I would do is to install the core via composer:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition
```

I can now write my custom module(s) and theme(s) under `app/code`. I would then add my `composer.*` and the whole `app/code` folder to my VCS. So far everything is fine.

Suppose now I want to use some build tools for my project, let's say Grunt or Gulp.

1. If I commit my own `Gruntfile.js`, this will be overwritten by the `magento/magento2-base` package when I run `composer install` after I cloned the repo.
2. If I commit my `gulpfile.js`, I can't really define my dependencies in a `package.json`, because it would also be overwritten by `magento/magento2-base`.
3. If I decide to use Magento's Grunt setup and want to customise it by editing the files under `/dev/tools/grunt` (e.g. `themes.js`), I can't because my changes would be overwritten by `magento/magento2-base`.

My understanding is that you can't really do much in your document root. There are of course plenty of solutions to this problem:

- I could run a `git checkout -` right after installation to reset my own files
- I could store my build files in a dedicated folder, `/build` for example
- I could use a different build tool, like Phing, Ant, or Rake (my frontend devs wouldn't be so happy though)
- I could replace `magento/magento2-base` with a custom package that has a custom mapping for core files (not really optimal but hey, it's an option)

I personally dislike all of these options, so I would like to know if there is a preferred or better way to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Is anyone having the same problem? How did you solve it? How do you structure your project under VCS?

**UPDATE**

An extra point related to the project setup. In my experiments I noticed that Magento composer installer has a flag for file overriding:

```
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
```

It is internally treated as a boolean if I'm not mistaken, so I tried to set it to `false` to skip overriding. When I run `composer install` my installation fails because of the file(s) being already present. Basically, if I don't let Magento override my files, I can't install it.

What is the purpose of this flag then? Is it only suppose to perform a check for me? It doesn't make much sense to me to be honest, but maybe someone can shed some light on the subject.

Comment: I'm curious to see what others post as an answer.  Ideally, I think we'd want to keep Magento Core out of our main repo and keep that limited to just the template we create and any custom plugins we add or right.  Then at build time, we reference the core + our project repo and build an application artifact from the repositories.  This is the method I have been using for M1 recently and I'm wondering if the official recommendation from Magento is to do something similar with M2 now that Composer is fully supported.

Comment: In newer M2 versions, the `Gruntfile.js`, `gulpfile.js` and `package.json` issue is solved. The issue addressed in this question is still applicable to newer Magento 2 versions when you need to change `themes.js`, `index.php` or `.htaccess` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looks like I found a better solution for what I was trying to achieve. In the `composer.json`, it is possible to specify which files should be ignored by the Magento Composer Installer. If I don't want my `Gruntfile.js` to be overridden, I can simply specify it with the following configuration:

```
"extra": {
    "magento-deploy-ignore": {
        "magento/magento2-base": [
            "/Gruntfile.js",
            "/package.json"
        ]
    }
}
```

I am now able to extend the standard installation to fit my needs.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem "upgrade safe". If Magento will make changes to these files you ignore, then you won't know or you will forget about these files. You are using your own version which will never include these new changes. Please check my answer for my suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Shortish term, we are looking to separate files that need customization. E.g. if people need to modify index.php, work out how to separate the standard file Magento ships from the need of local customizations. Once achieved, it is possible to have a "one true .gitignore for all projects can use". That is, easy to commit whole project directory to Git with .gitignore of everything that "composer install" will fetch for you (and everything "composer update" will replace when installing a patch or upgrade).

Longer term, the goal is to shorten .gitignore as much as possible. E.g. push more into modules under the 'vendor' directory.

Then

1. For everything you don't want to share across projects, leave it under app/code and committed in the main project repo.
2. Everything locally developed you want to share across projects more easily, put in a separate GIT repo and install via composer so it ends up under 'vendor'. (Could be a local composer repo, or just install straight from GIT.)

That way you can still git commit the whole project tree from the top down, capturing the composer.json and composer.lock files (committing just app/code does not). The .gitignore will exclude the 'vendor' directory and other files not wanted.

This gives you the best of both worlds mentioned in the other discussion. The current pain is the length and complexity of the .gitignore file, and patch installation currently wipes out some local customization (e.g. in index.php). Short term workaround - remove index.php from .gitignore, and when you install a patch check to see what changes you lost (git diff) and reapply them manually.

Comment: OK, so you will change some things there in the near future, nice! I wonder if this `"magento-force": "override"` flag could be useful somehow. At the moment it is not exactly doing what I would expect. In case you edited/extended your `index.php` or any other "core" files, you could simply tell Magento not to overwrite your changes. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy Solution for your override Problem: don't change core Files ;)
Magento is based on extending the Code and not changing it.

First thing is, you should not put your whole app/code folder in one vcs Repository. Each Magento Component (Module, Theme, etc...) should be a repository itself.

If you want to change/extend the frontend, you should create a new theme and treat this theme as your grunt project, not the whole Magento2 Instance.

To install your theme in your Project you can easily pull it in via composer directly from your vcs repository

Comment: Well, the `app/code` folder is specifically there to customise Magento. My understanding of the current M2 is that `app/code` replaces what `app/code/local` was in M1, and community modules can be installed via composer under `vendor`. We have some projects with a LARGE number of modules, and several themes as well. What you are suggesting would be impossible to manage.

Comment: Hey, we manage projects with >100 components that way. The key is to keep modules small and manage your composer dependencies between the modules. You can clone the magento project repository for your own needs and add all your components to your project

Comment: If you are happy with your current setup it's fine. Honestly, I find it rather cumbersome. It means you have 100+ git repositories, and every time you are changing something you have to open a specific project, commit your changes, run `composer update`. Where do you commit your `composer.lock` then? If you have 10+ devs working on the same project, it could turn out really messy. Of course we do have plenty of general modules (and themes even) that we install via composer, but project-specific code should be versioned under the same repo for the sake of clarity.

Comment: I'm not saying you are doing it wrong, I think it's a bit overcomplicated for my taste. Out of interest, how do you inspect your repo history with such a setup? How can you use features like `git blame` or `git log` when the code is scattered in multiple components? Do you run integration tests to see that everything is working fine?

Comment: we had this discussion internally last year and deployments got rather simple since we decided to make it 1repo=1module. The Point is that you would not make a composer update for one little change. Developers work in dev environments and change files there directly. When they are done, they can tag it as alpha, beta or release candidate. This way, several developers can work on many projects at the same time and the next time, you make a composer update you pull in all changes. There are great tools for organizing your vcs and composer packages.Hundreds of Repositories should not be a Problem

Comment: to inspect the history, you have to know of course, in which module you are looking for what changes. The integration tests environments have to be build with composer of course. But its also pretty easy because you can keep it persistent and update it before every test run

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the accepted answer, although being the way originally intended to achieve the desired goal, only work for excluding files and directories placed in the root, because if we want to exclude a file placed in a subdirectory (eg. `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js`, needed if we add a new theme and want to use Magento Grunt tasks), putting it in the "magento-deploy-ignore" configuration, it blocks the deploy of all parent directories (that is, dev and all its subdirectories).

This happen because the method that process the "magento-deploy-ignore" (`\MagentoHackathon\Composer\Magento\Deploystrategy\DeploystrategyAbstract::isDestinationIgnored`) use `strpos` to match the destination path against the list of excluded, so every parent path will always return true.

Comment: I know, I could see that in my tests, but since we are using a different build workflow it works fine for us atm. Could you find a better option?

Comment: We started doing the checkout of the files during the build phase of our pipeline, then we stopped using at all built-in Grunt tasks so atm it's not a problem.

Comment: By the way, we started evaluate of fork magento-composer-installer for enhance the "magento-deploy-ignore" behaviour, if the problem should reappear we could follow this path

Answer (score 0):

#### Using patches

What I use is creating and applying patches. When we need to change `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js`, `index.php` or `.htaccess` we apply the changes to a temporary copy of the file and create a patch out of it (create a `build/` dir first):

```
$ cp dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js.tmp
  # Now Make changes in .tmp file
$ diff -u3 dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js.tmp | sed 's/\.tmp//' > build/themes.patch
$ mv dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js.tmp dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js
```

Then we can make this patch apply automatically when running `composer install` or `update` by adding te commands to the `scripts` section of your `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": "patch -i build/themes.patch dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js",
        "post-update-cmd": "patch -i build/themes.patch dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js"
    }
}
```

*(Also you could put the above `patch ...` command in a bash script, let's say `build/themes_patch.sh` and call that script from Composer so it will be reusable or manually executable)*

#### Upgrade safe! :D

This solution is upgrade safe! You are not changing core files directly without respecting the original file. You are applying a patch to the original Magento2 file. When that file changes because you are upgrading, the patch will fail and you know that you have to take a closer look to the new changes and create a new patch.